# How to run CLISP code in javascript?

Tags: javascript, lisp, clisp

I am programming a connect 4 game to play against an AI I coded in CLISP. I made the GUI in javascript but can't make the connection between the two. I want to run the CLISP code in the browser using a js-lisp or a similar interpreter, but I can not make it work.

In my CLISP code you end up with a function called tira-final() which takes a string representation of the field and returns a position in which to shoot. I intend to do something like this to call it in javascript

```
function tiraAi(){
var str = "";
for (var x = 0; x <= 6; x++) {
    for (var y = 5; y >= 0; y--) {
        if(board[y][x] == 0)
            str = str + "0 ";          
        else{
            if(board[y][x] == "black")
                str = str + "1 ";
            else
                str = str + "2 ";
        }
    }
}

$(' .title').text(str);

x = (tira-final str dificultad);

return x;}
```

And this is how I referenced the interpreter:

```
<script src="/Users/diego/js-lisp/build/lisp.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  lisp.load("connect-4.lisp");
  </script>
```

Thanks!